# get metadata, ForEach and copy activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I want to copy 2 tables from blob storage to SQL Database.
**I created pipeline like this:-**
Get MetaData:- For capturing the files (2 csv files) in the input container
ForEach:- For iterating the files in input container
Copy activity:- Inside the ForEach. Copy both of the files in SQL database.

Now, when I started debugging, I got the error 2200 and it says userBlobDoesNotExists.

Here is the error code for the copy activity:-

```
    "copyDuration": 3,
    "errors": [
        {
            "Code": 9013,
            "Message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorSourceBlobNotExist,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The required Blob is missing. ContainerName: https://employeestorage1.blob.core.windows.net/employeeinput, path: employeeinput/workdetail.csv.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
            "EventType": 0,
            "Category": 5,
            "Data": {},
            "MsgId": null,
            "ExceptionType": null,
            "Source": null,
            "StackTrace": null,
            "InnerEventInfos": []
        }
    ],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US)",
    "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "DataMovement",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.06666666666666667,
                "unit": "DIUHours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
                "region": "East US"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
                "region": "East US"
            },
            "status": "Failed",
            "start": "2021-06-24T17:28:09.4507134Z",
            "duration": 3,
            "usedDataIntegrationUnits": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "profile": {
                "queue": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 2
                },
                "transfer": {
                    "status": "Completed",
                    "duration": 0
                }
            },
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 2,
                "transferDuration": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataConsistencyVerification": {
        "VerificationResult": "Unsupported"
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    }
}
```

**And here is the code for the pipeline:-**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "inputfolder",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "employeeinputdataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "for each table in input folder",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "inputfolder",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('inputfolder').output.Childitems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "wildcardFolderPath": "employeeinput",
                                        "wildcardFileName": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "employeeinputdataset",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "employeeoutputsql",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "OutputTableName": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't choose Wildcard file path in the File path type setting, please choose File path in dataset to have a try.

And you need to create a parameter in your Source dataset. In the File path of Source dataset, type the `@dataset().fileName` expression. Finally, pass `@item().name` to the parameter of dataset is ok.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution didn't solve directly, but indirectly it solved my problem, thank you.